# 2D rotation and collision detection in Unity3d with C# Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, 2d, collision

I have a game object, a yellow circle that shown in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snwy7.png) as my player object and the red one is the child of my player object.

Then If i press spacebar key once, it will rotate by -90 degrees [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBafN.png)

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhWCd.png) is when i press the spacebar key twice, my player rotating perfectly but it stuck and continue vibrating hitting the pink block.My question is, how can i modify my script to make the player know if it just only can rotate once and prevent the player from rotating again if i press the spacebar key because of the pink block will barrier it rotation.

Here is my Player rotator script.

```css
public GameObject objToRotate;
 private bool rotating = false;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
     
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
     if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) 
     {
         StartRotation ();
     }
     
     
 }
 private IEnumerator Rotate(Vector3 angles, float duration)
 {
     rotating = true;
     Quaternion startRotation = objToRotate.transform.rotation;
     Quaternion endRotation = Quaternion.Euler (angles) * startRotation;
     for (float t = 0; t < duration; t += Time.deltaTime) {
         objToRotate.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (startRotation, endRotation, t / duration);
         yield return null;
     }
     objToRotate.transform.rotation = endRotation;
     rotating = false;
 }
 public void StartRotation()
 {
     if (!rotating)
         StartCoroutine (Rotate (new Vector3 (0, 0, -90), 1.1f));
 }
```

Sorry if i not good in english. Every comments and help are very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your coroutine to run just once you can modify it like this

```
public GameObject objToRotate;
private bool rotating = false;
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !rotating)
    {
        StartRotation();
    }


}
private IEnumerator Rotate(Vector3 angles, float duration)
{
    rotating = true;
    Quaternion startRotation = objToRotate.transform.rotation;
    Quaternion endRotation = Quaternion.Euler(angles) * startRotation;
    for (float t = 0; t < duration; t += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        objToRotate.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startRotation, endRotation, t / duration);
        yield return null;
    }
    objToRotate.transform.rotation = endRotation;

}
public void StartRotation()
{
    if (!rotating)
        StartCoroutine(Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -90), 1.1f));
}
```